# Show following users post in react native and firebase

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, social-media

I'm developing an app with react native + firebase and I would like to add the possibility to see the posts of the users I follow (like instagram). Can anyone tell me how to do it?  thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty broad considering there's no context to what you want the app to do, but I'm assuming you'd like to use the API's hosted by Facebook, Instagram, etc. You'd need to read the documentation given by each social media website. Here are the links to the bigger API sites you'll probably need.

- Twitter API  https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs.html
- Facebook API https://developers.facebook.com/docs
- Instagram Graph API
  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/

If you give a more specific question, we can give more specific answers

Comment: Yes sorry,maybe my question is too short.I have a listView that need to show posts. I would like this listView to show only the posts of the people I follow (inside my app).